# Element type "settings" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd

```
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 
                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"  
          xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance ">
```

Comment: <settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"  
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance ">

Comment: this is the actual text that is throwing error at the begging of the xml document . can somebody suggest what is the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As a general rule, take your time to write your question so that we readers can see clearly: What do you want, what have you tried, what happened then.

Answer (score 1):

All XML Elements Must Have a Closing Tag

So the error is quite clear. You either need to write

```
...stance "></settings>
```

or

```
...stance " />
```

at the end of your XML.

Also have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp